# Create .EML file in Django and return as response

Tags: python, django, email

I am trying to store an email as a eml file in Django. I have seen links that use the python email generator to create the email and store it to a file on the OS, and I have code that makes an email in the EmailMultiAlternatives class in Django.

What I want is to create the email using the EmailMultiAlternatives class and instead of sending it just download the .eml file (gives the user chance to make changes to the file before sending along with other reasons that have been requested by the client).

Is there anyway of doing this? I looked at the class and there is no save functionality for the class - only send.

Comment: Perhaps look into Django [email file backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#file-backend) and how it's implemented...